# is there any way to control recyclerview scrolling like page flip?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am using a  recyclerview to scroll between  pdf pages for a book app
**my problem is** : i need a way to stop smooth scrolling for
example swype  from right to the middle of screen brings next page   if the user stop swyping before reach the middle of screen the application keep current page.

Like this one:

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think you may be looking for [LinearSnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearSnapHelper).